# POST a string value to firebase using angular-1 $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I using angularjs1 in ionic-1 application and Firebase Database.
And I am trying to post a string to the database using firebase REST API.
I want the data to be in the following format:
Firebase generated  Key: "My string"

[image]

But what I actually get is :

[image]

Can anyone help me to know how to send the data in http post function as a string ?

Here is my code:

```js
.service('postFollowedUser', ['$http', '$q','baseURL', function($http, $q,baseURL){
      var deferObject,
        myMethods = {
          postUser: function(uid,followedUid) {
            var myPromise =  $http({
                method:'POST',
                url: baseURL+'users/'+uid+'/followedUsers.json',
                data:{followedUid}
                }),
              deferObject = deferObject || $q.defer();

             myPromise.then(
              // OnSuccess function
              function(answer){
                // This code will only run if we have a successful promise.
                //alert('answer in servics'+JSON.stringify( answer));
                deferObject.resolve(answer);
              },
              // OnFailure function
              function(reason){
                // This code will only run if we have a failed promise.
                //alert(JSON.stringify( reason));
                deferObject.reject(reason);
              });

            return deferObject.promise;
          }
    };

      return myMethods;
  }])
```

I tried to removing the curly braces but I got the following error:

**"Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value."**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is supported by firebase, but you are sending payload with object (`data:{followedUid}` is the same as `data:{followedUid: followedUid}`).

Try removing the curly braces:

```
$http({
    method:'POST',
    url: baseURL+'users/'+uid+'/followedUsers.json',
    data: JSON.stringify(followedUid) // payload will be just the value of `followedUid` 
})
```

Btw I am not sure what dark magic are you trying to do with the `deferObject` :] You can simply return the `$http` call, its return value is already a promise. You can still call `then` on it to process the results:

```
return $http.post(baseURL + 'users/' + uid + '/followedUsers.json', JSON.stringify(followedUid))
    .then(function(answer) {
        console.log(answer);

        // return the answer so you can work with it later (again via `then`)
        return answer; 
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);

        // throw the error so you can catch it later (possibly via `catch`)
        throw error; 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your feedback.
I already tried to remove the curly braces but I got the following error

"Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value."

Comment: That is because of angular sending content type JSON, try setting it to `text/plain` via `headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}`. But as I noted, I am not sure if this is supported by firebase.

Comment: And if I remember correctly, there will be also problem with firebase, as you are using the `...json` endpoint, which will probably expect JSON payload only.

Comment: Maybe you could try to make the payload JSON (which in case of string means wrapping it with quotes). `data: JSON.stringify(followedUid)` or `data: '"' + followedUid + '"'`.

Comment: Both `data: JSON.stringify(followedUid)` and `data: '"' + followedUid + '"' ` worked well without specifying the `Content-Type`
Thanks a lot, I appreciate your help